# Initializing object variables - a Java approach, a Python approach?

Tags: python

I have an object that needs to have some 4-5 values passed to it. To illustrate:

```
class Swoosh():
    spam = ''
    eggs = ''
    swallow = ''
    coconut = ''

    [... methods ...]
```

Right now, the way to use `Swoosh` is:

```
swoosh = Swoosh()
swoosh.set_spam('Spam!')
swoosh.set_eggs('Eggs!')
swoosh.set_swallow('Swallow!')
swoosh.set_coconut('Migrated.')
```

I'm having doubts whether this is Pythonic or is this too much Java influence. Or is it just necessary? Also, in case you're wondering why I'm using setters instead of simply accessing the object variables - some basic validation has to be done there, hence the `set_` methods.

I reckon I could provide a different way to initialize a `Swoosh` - provide an `__init__()` that would accept a `dict`/`list`?

Anyway, I'm just looking for help/advice from someone more experienced with this stuff.

Thanks in advance for any input on this.

Comment: Why do so many people nowadays write `class SomeThing():` if the empty parens serve absolutely no purpose? Or is it too much hard work to insert `object` between those?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Firstly you're using old style classes.  You **really, really** should be using [new style classes that inherit from `object`](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-new-style-class):

```
class Swoosh(object):
```

Defining an `__init__` method that takes arguments is definitely the Pythonic way of doing things:

```
def __init__(self,spam,eggs,swallow,coconut):
    self.spam = spam
    self.eggs = eggs
    self.swallow = swallow
    self.coconut = coconut
```

This would allow you to do:

```
s = Swoosh('Spam!','Eggs','Swallow','Migrated')
```

Like any other Python function the `__init__` method can have default values for arguments, e.g.

```
def __init__(self,spam,eggs,swallow,coconut='Migrated.'):
        self.spam = spam
        self.eggs = eggs
        self.swallow = swallow
        self.coconut = coconut
```

If you want to validate attributes as they're set you should use standard [`property` attributes](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) rather than creating your own setters.  If you do it this way you can use `myobject.spam` in your code like with an ordinary attribute but your setter method is still run.

For example:

```
@property
def spam(self):
    """I'm the 'spam' property."""
    return self._spam

@spam.setter
def spam(self, value):
    if not value.endswith("!"):
        raise ValueError("spam must end with !")
    # Store the value in "private" _spam attribute
    self._spam = value

@spam.deleter
def spam(self):
    del self._spam
```

Note: `property` will **not work** unless you're using new-style classes as described above.

In your example you have:

```
class Swoosh():
    spam = ''
    eggs = ''
    swallow = ''
    coconut = ''
```

This is often presented as a quick way of setting defaults for attributes for an object.  It's fine but you need to understand what is actually happening. What's going on is that you're setting attributes on the *class*.  If an object doesn't have an attribute Python will look to see if it's defined on the class and return the value from there (as this is what you want for methods).

If you want to set default values for object attributes you're much better off setting default values for the arguments in `__init__` as described above rather than using `class` attributes.

Comment: +1 for the new style classes and the warning about class vs. instance attributes!

Answer (score 11):

First of all, this:

```
class Swoosh():
    spam = ''
    eggs = ''
    swallow = ''
    coconut = ''
```

sets *class* attributes `spam`, `eggs`, etc. Your set_spam method would then presumably go ahead and create *object* attributes of the same name that hide the class attributes. In other words, defining these attributes have no effect and just confuses things.

I would do it like this, if all the variables are optional:

```
class Swoosh():
    def __init__(self, spam="", eggs="", swallow="", coconut=""):
        self.spam = spam
        self.eggs = eggs
        self.swallow = swallow
        self.coconut = coconut
```

Then you can create objects like this:

```
o1 = Swoosh(eggs="Eggs!", coconut="Carried by the husk")
```

If, say, spam and eggs are mandatory, then substitute with

```
    def __init__(self, spam, eggs, swallow="", coconut=""):
```

And don't use setters and getters at all. If you need to later on, you can seamlessly replace a regular attribute with a property by adding code like this to your class:

```
    def get_spam(self):
        return self._spam
    def set_spam(self, value):
        self._spam = " ".join([str(value)] * 5)
    spam = property(get_spam, set_spam)
```

With the above change, this:

```
o2 = Swoosh(eggs="yes", spam="spam")
print o2.spam
```

prints

```
spam spam spam spam spam
```

**Note:** As Dave Webb points out in his answer, you need to subclass `object` for properties to work, unless you use python 3.0+, in which case classes implicitly subclass `object`. Oh, and *do* follow Sean Vieira's link to the *Python is not Java* article. It's a must-read.

Answer (score 6):

Basic validation can be done by overriding the appropriate [get and set methods on the class](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access) (if the validation needs to be done in all cases) or by altering the specific property with the [`property`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) built-in.  Remember, [Python is not Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html) (Of course, [Java is not Python, either](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/java-is-not-python-either.html)).

As for how you want to do your class creation, you have a couple of choices:

1) Use the `__init__` method with keyword args to let people provide as much or as little as they want to your constructor:

```
class Swoosh(object): # Get new-object goodness
    def __init__(self, spam='', eggs='', swallow='', coconut=''):
        # We are going to be using properties in this example
        self._spam = spam
        self._eggs = eggs
        self._swallow = swallow
        self._coconut = coconut
```

2) Continue doing things the way you are, but update the class attributes to be instance attributes:

```
class Swoosh(object): # Get new-object goodness
    def __init__(self):
        self.spam = ''
        self.eggs = ''
        self.swallow = ''
        self.coconut = ''
```

The way you are doing it currently, every instance of `Swoosh` shares the same values for these variables, and changing the value of `spam` on `Swoosh` will change it *for every instance of `Swoosh` that hasn't set up an instance attribute with the same name* (Which probably isn't what you want.)

Either way, you should look into removing the getters and setters and replacing them with properties (when you do this will of course depend on how public and widely used this API is):

```
# Inside class Swoosh's definition
@property
def spam(self):
    return self._spam
@spam.setter
def spam(self, value):
    # Validate that it's really SPAM, not WHAM!
    # And only then replace the underlying value
    self._spam = value
@spam.deleter
def spam(self):
    del self._spam
# Rinse and repeat for other properties that need access control
```

Comment: `The way you are doing it currently, every instance of Swoosh shares the same values for these variables, and changing the value of spam in one instance will change it for every instance of spam (Which probably isn't what you want.)` This is wrong

Comment: @Dikei - quite correct - updated to the more correct "changing the value of `spam` on `Swoosh` will change it for every instance of `Swoosh` that hasn't set up an instance attribute with the same name".  Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 4):

To initialize Swoosh values you have multiple choices :

First, the constructor args :

```
class Swoosh(object):
   def __init__(self, spam, eggs, swallow, coconut):
      self.spam = spam
      self.eggs = eggs
      self.swallow = swallow
      self.coconut = coconut
```

And then instanciate your obejct like this :

```
swoosh = Swoosh("spam", "eggs", "swallow", "coconut")
```

If you need more control on the way you get/set the values, you can the use [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) method.

```
class Swoosh():
   def __init__(self, spam, eggs, swallow, coconut):
      self.spam = spam
      self.eggs = eggs
      self.swallow = swallow
      self.coconut = coconut

  def set_spam(self, value):
     #do verification stuff
     self._spam = value

  def get_spam(self):
     #do what you want/need before get the value
     return self._spam

  spam = property(get_spam, set_spam)
```

And then, every call like `swoosh.spam = spam_value` will call the `set_spam` method, and `foo = swoosh.spam` will call the `get_spam` method.

Answer (score 2):

The `__init__()` function is what you want to use to set values when the object is first created.

Eg.

```
class Swoosh:
    __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.arg3 = arg3
```